# InfoPath 2007 Client form does not open on my machine

Tags: 2007, infopath

We have a moss2007 site with form libraries having client infopath forms published directly to it. When I click on new in the form library i receive the following error.

> **Form template: siteURL/Forms/template.xsn
>
>   The following form template**
>   **for the form cannot be found: siteURL/Forms/template.xsn**

This same form was opening previously. But now it does not.

I also tried checking by giving the *siteURL/Forms/template.xsn url* directly in the browser. It opens the file open save dialog. 
When i choose open, I receive this error.

> **Could not open 'Site**
>   **Url/formLibraryName/Forms/template.xsn?OpenIn=PreferClient&NoRedirect=true&XsnLocation=formLibraryName/forms/template.xsn'.**

But if I choose save and save the template on my local machine and then double click on it in my local machine it opens without any error. 
I am really not able to figure out what is wrong.

Breaking my head over solving this problem as I cannot find anything in the error logs. Does any one know how to fix this error? 
Thanks in advance for all help.